# Cypress setup default path aliases

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress, rollup

All my Imports use a **webpack/rollup** default path to import my **.js** files is under **src/**.

My project is:

```
project-name/
    node_modules/
    cypress/
    src/
    ...
```

Then, when I run test into **Cypress** I wouldn't have error to import dependencies.

How can I setup a default project forlder for **src**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

> cypress/plugins/index.js

If you are using webpack, add you webpack config into this file.

```
const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');


module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = {

      webpackOptions: require('../../build/webpack.config'),
      watchOptions: {},
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options));
};

// send in the options from your webpack.config.js, so it works the same
// as your app's code
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that if somebody works with Cypress on Docker (like for example one of their official images https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images) then `webpack-preprocessor` is available as global module under `/root/.cache/Cypress/<your_cypress_version>/Cypress/resources/app/npm/webpack-preprocessor` path.

Comment: Using `webpack` alias (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) it can go like this:

```js
;module.exports = (on, config) => {
    const preprocPath = `${config.env.CACHE_FOLDER}/${config.version}/Cypress/resources/app/npm/webpack-preprocessor`;
    const preproc = require(preprocPath);
    const options = {
        webpackOptions: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    'alias-name': 'path/to/module'
                },
            },
        },
    };

    on('file:preprocessor', preproc(options));
};
```